# How can we get the PDF of a non-monotonic function?

Tags: probability, inverse-function

For random variable $x$, we have the PDF $f_x(x)$ and $y=g(x),x=h(y)$ which both are monotonic easily, there would be the PDF of y:

$$
f_y(y)=f_x(h(y))|h'(y)|
$$

But what if $g(x)$ is not monotonic? For instance, $g(x)=J_1(x)$, in which $J_n(x)$ is the first kind of bessel function.

All I can come up with is numerical way or separate $g(x)$ into different monotonic parts. Is there any other equations or formulas made for non-monotonic $g(x)$?.

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks for reading!

Comment: You may want to sum over the different $x$ which lead to the same value of $y=g(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to seek for a partition $\langle A_i\rangle $ of the sample space $\mathcal X$ that *makes* the transformation monotonic. More formally, consider the functions $g_i$ defined on $A_i$ such that $g_i(x) =g(x) $ on $A_i, ~g_i$ is monotone in $A_i.$ Assuming they have the same range $\mathcal Y, $ if $g^{-1}$ has a continuous derivative in $\mathcal Y, $ then it is easy to see $$f_Y(y) =\begin{cases}\sum f_X\left(g_i^{-1}(y)\right)\left\vert\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}g_i^{-1}(y))\right\vert&y\in\mathcal Y, \\0&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Even if the range isn't same, then one can proceed by taking $\mathcal Y_i$ as the range of $g_i.$ That is, for each $i, ~ g_i:A_i\to \mathcal Y_i$ is monotone.

Then, $$f_Y(y) =\sum \mathbf 1_{\mathcal 
Y_i}f_X\left(g_i^{-1}(y)\right)\left\vert\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}g_i^{-1}(y))\right\vert.$$

This approach is in the line of Henry's advice.

Comment: Thanks. @Enforce. Wrote it in haste and bit inattentiveness. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @User1865345
Thank you! But could you tell me what is $1_{A_{i}}$? I have never seen it before.

Comment: This is the identity function: $\mathbf 1_X(x):=\begin{cases}1&x\in X, \\0&x\notin X\end{cases}.$ @XiangyuCui

Comment: @User1865345
Thanks! Got it!

Comment: I have now deleted my previous comments since they were not relevant to the answer as it is now.

Comment: I will leave mine as a remainder of your feedback @Enforce.